# Why not works ClickListeners for Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, materialdrawer

I use MaterialDrawer and code MainActivity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements KitchenFragment.CallbackOne {
    public static final String TAG = "myLogTag";

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private Drawer drawer;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "CLICK NOCL");
            }
        });
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);


        fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = MenuFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();

        }

        drawer = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(mToolbar)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.menu).withIdentifier(1),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.kitchen_title).withIdentifier(2),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.information_title).withEnabled(false)
                ).withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "position clicked: " + position);
                        Fragment fragment = MenuFragment.newInstance();
                        switch (position) {
                            case 1:
                                fragment = MenuFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                fragment = KitchenFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            default:
                                fragment = new Fragment();
                        }
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .withFireOnInitialOnClick(true)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withOnDrawerNavigationListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerNavigationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationClickListener(View view) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "CLICK in DNL");
                        if (!drawer.getActionBarDrawerToggle().isDrawerIndicatorEnabled()) {
                            onBackPressed();
                            return true;
                        } else
                            return false;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CLICK OIS");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState = drawer.saveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen())
            drawer.closeDrawer();
        else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            drawer.getActionBarDrawerToggle().syncState();
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFirstSelected() {
        drawer.setSelection(1);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to trace a Click in `mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener`
and `withOnDrawerNavigationListener` and `onOptionsItemSelected`. 
None of the listeners not reacted for clicking.

How you see i use `Activity` that launches `Fragment` (1), which in turn lets `Fragment` (2 and 3). In 2 and 3 `Fragment`  in `OnCreate` i use `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` , and I need to by pressing the back button (in toolbar), returning the previous fragment, and not open Drawer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MaterialDrawer already handles all the listeners for you. If you need to do an action after the drawer opens or closes you can provide the listener via the `DrawerBuilder`

For the icon you have this listener:
`OnDrawerNavigationListener`
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/DrawerBuilder.java#L1158

For drawer close / open this listener:
`OnDrawerListener`
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/DrawerBuilder.java#L1116

Comment: Wow, Mike! Hi, and thanks for the answer, but maybe I'm wrong to expressed it - I need to be on a fragment of 2 and 3 by pressing the Back button (in the toolbar, the one that changes with a hamburger on the arrow) back to the previous fragment, and did not open the Drawer. I realized that all the listeners found, but none of them does not work when you press the back arrow

Comment: How have you defined the back arrow? You checked if the home event is triggered in the fragment instead of the activity?

Comment: in fragment in onCreate i use ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); for define back arrow

Comment: Hmm I think the arrow event is then not sent via the listners you can provide for the drawer, but via the general `onOptionsItemSelected`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create new `Activity` using android studio wizard. File->New->Activity->Navigation Drawer Activity.
In that case `ActionBarDrawerToaggle` is used

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
```

This toggle contains click listener which handle open/close drawer functionality for you. 
Also you can that item clicks implemented through `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

Comment: when i used standart DrawerLayout (not MikePenz Library) - 
there were no problems and everything was working correctly